# Привязка видимости CheckBox к свойству IsSelected элемента в списке

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

> Необходимо соблюдение MVVM

Проблема такова, я через ItemsSource передаю в список коллекцию объектов. Шаблон данного списка выглядит так:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="15"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="13"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price}" FontSize="13"/>
        <CheckBox/>
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

И как видите там в конце шаблона затисался CheckBox. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы он был видимым только тогда, когда данный элемент выбран, т.е. у других объектов он будет невидимым, пока их не выберут, но проблема в том, что мы передаем напрямую список объектов, а не привычный ListBoxItem, у которого можно было бы привязать видимость чекбокса к свойству IsSelected элемента и дальше использовать конвертер. Что в такой ситуации можно сделать?

Comment: Сделайте у vm свойство IsSelected {get;set;} на который забиндиваете Visibilty чекбокса (с конвертером). А в ListBox  добавляйте SelectedItem={Binding CurrentItem} где в сеттере устанавливаете IsSelected  у нового текущего и снимаете у прежнего текущего

Comment: @vitidev что-то я не понял, что делать после добавления `SelectedItem={Binding CurrentItem}`? Если можно поподробнее

Comment: `{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}, Converter=...}` ну или тоже самое с помощью триггера, тогда даже конвертер не понадобится

Comment: @АндрейNOP спасибо, ваш вариант тоже сильно помог

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создадим стиль для `ListBoxItem`:

```
<Style x:Key="MyListboxItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Border>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="15"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="13"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price}" FontSize="13"/>
                        <CheckBox x:Name="CB" Opacity="0" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="CB" Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Собственно, создавать его по хорошему нужно не с нуля, а на основе уже существующего (и использующегося у вас стиля), куда аккуратненько подпихнуть это.

Сам же код `Listbox'a` будет выглядеть вот так:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource MyListboxItemStyle}"></ListBox>
```

В нем больше нет необходимости задавать `ItemTemplate`, ибо все это уже задано в стиле.